# Error running excel vba code from PERSONAL.XLBS: Compile error: User-defined type not defined

Tags: excel, vba, download, xmlhttprequest

I’ve written some VBA code to download some photos from our online database.  Our database can dump to an excel file by running a report which includes web addresses of the photos.  I’d like to have the person be able to run the report and then run the macro with a keystroke and download the photos without having to open an additional workbook.  I cobbled this sub together from some code that I found online and customized it to fit my needs. I wrote it as a module in a workbook and it works great.  When I moved it to the PERSONAL.XLSB project, it does not work.  Moved it back again and it works from the workbook.  In order to get it to work in the first place, I had to go to Tools->References and enable “Microsoft Scripting Runtime” and “Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library”.  The failure point is the line “Dim xmlhttp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60”.  I get the error:  “Compile error: User-defined type not defined".  I’m thinking that this has something to do with  it not being able to use the enabled references when it is in the PERSONAL.XLSB project.  This is really beyond my experience.  Can anyone give me some idea of how to make this work?

code below:

```
   Option Explicit

   Private Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
    Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, ByVal szURL As String, _
    ByVal szFileName As String, ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long

   Sub download_all_photos()
    
    Dim wk As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim counter As Integer
    
    
    Dim xmlhttp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    
    Dim myURL As String, typ As String, name0 As String, name2 As String
    Dim catname As String
    Dim name1 As String, xstate As String, dlpath As String
    Dim pos As Integer
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim FileExists As String
    Dim xstatus As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim lastRow_photos As Long
    Dim lastrow_Current As Integer
    Dim Sheet As Variant
    Dim CurrentRange As Range
    Dim purl As String
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    
    ' About to create a new "photo_url" sheet, delete any old one
    For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Sheet.Name = "photo_url" Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            Worksheets("photo_url").Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
    Next Sheet
    
    Sheets.Add.Name = "photo_url"
    
    lastrow_Current = Worksheets("Current").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    
    j = 1
    For i = 2 To lastrow_Current
    
        purl = Worksheets("Current").Cells(i, 19).Value
        If purl <> "" Then
        
            purl = Replace(purl, Chr(34), "")
            purl = Replace(purl, "<a target=_blank href=", "")
            purl = Replace(purl, ">Photo Link</a>", "")
            Worksheets("photo_url").Cells(j, 1).Value = purl
            Worksheets("photo_url").Cells(j, 2).Value = Worksheets("Current").Cells(i, 2).Value
            Worksheets("photo_url").Cells(j, 3).Value = Worksheets("Current").Cells(i, 3).Value
            Worksheets("photo_url").Cells(j, 4).Value = Replace(Worksheets("Current").Cells(i, 7).Value, "/ ", "_")
        
            
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next i
    
    Worksheets("photo_url").Columns("A:D").AutoFit


    lastRow_photos = Worksheets("photo_url").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    dlpath = Worksheets("Instructions").Range("A1").Value
    counter = 0
    
    
    For i = 1 To lastRow_photos
    
        myURL = Worksheets("photo_url").Range("A" & i).Value
        catname = Worksheets("photo_url").Range("C" & i).Value & "_" & Worksheets("photo_url").Range("B" & i).Value     'use if want to add shelterluv ID
  
        xmlhttp.Open "GET", myURL, False
        xmlhttp.send
        
        name0 = xmlhttp.getResponseHeader("Content-Disposition")
        
        If name0 <> "" Then
            pos = InStr(1, name0, "=")
            name2 = Mid(name0, pos + 1, (Len(name0) - (pos)))
        Else
            name2 = FileNameFromPath(myURL)
        End If
        
        FileName = dlpath & "\" & catname & ".png"
        FileExists = Dir(FileName)
        If FileExists = "" Then
            name2 = catname
        Else
            name2 = catname & Int(2 + Rnd * (100000 - 2 + 1))   ' add a random number to name
        End If
        
        Debug.Print myURL; FileName

              
        xstatus = URLDownloadToFile(0, myURL, FileName, 0, 0)
        
        Debug.Print xstatus
        
    Next i
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    End Sub

    Function FileNameFromPath(strFullPath As String) As String

    FileNameFromPath = Right(strFullPath, Len(strFullPath) - InStrRev(strFullPath, "/"))

  End Function
```

Comment: You also need a reference to `Microsoft XML, 6.0`.

Comment: References are specific to a Workbook.   You'll need to add them to `PERSONAL.XLSB` as well.

Comment: Thanks to both of you VBasic2008 & Chris Neilsen.  Your suggestions solved my problem.